# Unable to send compressed zip file from a Mac

Tags: macbook-pro, filesystem, python, file-sharing, file-transfer

I was given a Google link to upload a zip file containing some python scripts and screenshots. But for some reason I wasn't able to click on the required zip file when the Finder opened up, but I was able to individually select the screenshots. I also noticed I wasn't able to individually select the python files.

When I realized they dont accept .py files, I decided to remove the .py files from my compressed zip files and only kept the screenshots.

Still I am unable to select it.

Note: My Windows friends are able to do so

Could anyone help me out with this issue?

Comment: Was this "in the Finder", or was it a File Open dialog in a browser? Which browser are you using?

Comment: Also, what do you mean with "Google link"? To which site are you trying to upload data?

Comment: @benwiggy Ok I didn't know how to phrase it, but yes it was a file open dialog in a browser. The browser which I use is Chrome.

Comment: @nohillside I was asked to submit it as an assignment so we have this discord group where they sent this link in which we had to drag the zip file from the finder inside this link.

Comment: For problems involving Chrome, the first step is to test another (better) browser.

Comment: If you can drag the ZIP file, why do you even open a File Open dialog instead?